# App crashing while using CameraKit with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2

I've been trying to implement CameraKit in my app using Kotlin. I was following [this](https://medium.com/camerakit/getting-started-with-camerakit-v1-0-0-beta1-3fee6d108e5f) tutorial. It's written in Java so I was converting it to Kotlin.

Here's the main_activity.java from the tutorial:

```
import com.camerakit.CameraKitView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CameraKitView cameraKitView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cameraKitView = findViewById(R.id.camera);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        cameraKitView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        cameraKitView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        cameraKitView.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Here's my cameraScreen.kt file, the Kotlin equivalent to above code:

```
package com.example.testapp
import com.camerakit.CameraKitView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle


class cameraScreen : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var cameraKitView:CameraKitView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_screen)
        cameraKitView = findViewById(R.id.camera)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        cameraKitView.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        cameraKitView.onPause()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        cameraKitView.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error on my `private var cameraKitView:CameraKitView` line

> Property must be initialised or be abstract

Here's what I've tried so far

- Tried using `lateinit` - app crashed
- Tried using `abstract` - app crashed
- Tried putting the line in an `init{...}` block. Then the lower functions can't see it.

Keep in mind that all this camera stuff is in another activity which I'm linking to my main activity using a button. If I remove everything in the cameraScreen.kt file, the activity switches fine, so I don't think the issue is there.

How do I solve this?

Comment: what does `activity_main` look like?

Comment: @Zun nothing much, just a button that links points to the cameraScreen activity

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the

```
cameraKitView = findViewById(R.id.camera);
```

part of the code. You should either do that or use synthetics.

You need to also change `var cameraKitView` to `lateinit var cameraKitView`

Comment: I did put the line there. Still getting the same error

Comment: You also need to declare it as `lateinit var`.

Comment: Tried that @tynn in combination with the answer. I am now getting a black screen. I granted the app permission to use the camera as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the the camera kit view.

doing this in kotlin:

```
var string : String
```

Isn't me initialising a string, its just strongly typing or defining the variable.

You need to tell your cameraKitView what its referring to.

For example if your XML looks like this:

```
<com.camerakit.CameraKitView
        android:id="@+id/cv_cameraview"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        app:camera_facing="back"
        app:camera_flash="auto"
        app:camera_focus="continuous"
        app:camera_permissions="camera">
</com.camerakit.CameraKitView>
```

In your class you need to do this in your oncreate:

also from my personal experience don't forget the rest of the lifecycle:

```
private lateinit var cameraKitView: CameraKitView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_punch)

    cameraKitView = cv_camerkit

}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    cameraKitView.onStart()

}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    cameraKitView.onResume()

}

public override fun onPause() {
    cameraKitView.onPause()
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onStop() {
    cameraKitView.onStop()
    super.onStop()
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the `var cameraKitView: CameraKitView = cv_camerkit` part. What goes after the = ? Also, is it necessary to include the rest of the lifecycle?

Comment: Yes for this library it is otherwise it will give you a black screen when you resume the view. I edited my answer as I didnt mean to add the var in the second time.

Comment: Also i'm using androidx so I dont have to intialise my views in my class for example with: findViewById(R.id.camera);  I can just refer to the views name

Comment: As you suggested, on including the whole lifecycle the camera worked. However, if I press the back button to go back to the main activity and then go to the camera activity again, I get a black screen. Note that I have not included the line `cameraKitView = cv_camerkit` as I do not know what to put after the `=` sign. My XML reads `android:id="@+id/camera"`

Comment: Possibly add cameraKitView.stop() in to your onbackpressed function. also instead of cv_camerakit you would then just use camera

Comment: I tried doing `onBackPressed(cameraKitView.stop())` but I'm getting this error 
>Too many arguments for public open fun onBackPressed(): Unit defined in com.example.testapp.cameraScree